# How can I stop the results from this SQL query replacing prior results?

Tags: php, sql

I'm using the following HTML form

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="number" placeholder="first" name="first">
    <input type="number" placeholder="last" name="last">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Along with this PHP

```
$first = $_POST["first"];
$last = $_POST["last"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT $first, $last";
```

This successfully returns the entries between first and last when the values are posted through the form. However any priory fetched results disappear when a new query is made. How can I make it so that new results are added to the BOTTOM of the list of old results when a new request is posted through the form?

Comment: Have you tried without having `LIMIT`

Comment: The problem there is that every time you click the submit button, you are sending the form via post and the page will reload. If you want to add the result of different queries at the same page you would have to do it via AJAX.

Comment: Agreed with both of these. Either Ajax to retrieve your paginated data so your page doesn't reload, or ignore $first and always set it to 0. ajax is the right way to go though, and it's too broad to answer here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you a very basic example of what you would have to try.

We have a page in HTML with a form and a div to store the results.
In that document we have aswell a little Javascript code to handle the form submit event.
For the Ajax query I did it the lazy way using jQuery. If you are not able to use that library in your code please let me know it.

**myPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form id="myForm"><!--Note there's no methods here-->
        <input id="inputFirst" type="number" placeholder="first" name="first">
        <input id="inputLast" type="number" placeholder="last" name="last">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="divResults">
      <!--Results will be displayed here-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code at the same document (**myPage.html**).

```
<!--Loading jQuery for easy Ajax methods-->
<!--(You can download it to your server)-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  // These first sentences aren't even necessary in main browsers
  var divResults = window.document.getElementById("divResults");
  var myForm = window.document.getElementById("myForm");
  var inputFirst = window.document.getElementById("inputFirst");
  var inputLast = window.document.getElementById("inputLast");

  // Listening for submit button
  myForm.addEventListener('submit', sendMyAmazingAjax);

  function sendMyAmazingAjax(e) {

    // To avoid the form to be send by direct post method
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $.ajax({
      url: 'myAmazingScript.php', // These are well self explained
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        first: inputFirst.value, // Content of form inputs
        last: inputLast.value
      },
      success: function (data) {
        // data is anything you "echo" in the PHP document
        // We add it to the current contents of divResults (if any)
        divResults.innerHTML += data;
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Now some PHP in a different document (**myAmazingScript.php**).
(You could do it in the same document but it's a little more tricky and not necessary at all).

I don't know which method are you using to make the queries to the database. I chose prepared staments for the example because it's safe, easy and still very extended.

```
<?php

// Creating connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'myAmazingDatabase');

// Checking connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}

$first = $_POST["first"];
$last = $_POST["last"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT ?, ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
  $stmt->bind_param('ii', $first, $last);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo 'First field: ' . $row['myAmazingFirstField'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Second field: ' . $row['myAmazingSecondField'] . '<br>';
    // Etc...
  }

  $stmt->free_result();
  $stmt->close();
}
```

I didn't try it but I think I didn't forget anything important. Let me know if you have any questions.

(Of course, you would have to change many "amazing names")

Comment: Excellent answer, many thanks for your help.